# Bison: $1 doesn't return the entire token value

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

```
test:   
    '( expr ')'
    {
        cout << $<string_type>2 << endl;
    }
    ;

expr:
    or_expr
    ;

or_expr:
    and_expr
    | or_expr T_OR and_expr
    ;

and_expr:
    equality_expr
    | and_expr T_AND equality_expr
    ;

equality_expr:
    relational_expr
    | equality_expr T_EQU relational_expr
    | equality_expr T_NEQ relational_expr
    ;

relational_expr:
    unary_expr 
    etc...
```

if I try to parse: var_i != var_j, what cout << $2 << endl; returns to me is just var_i and not the entire var_i != var_j. How do I fix?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're setting `$$` in any of the `expr` rules, so you should get random garbage when you read `$2`...

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments: See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments). )

@Chris Dodd wrote: Doesn't look like you're setting `$$` in any of the expr rules, so you should get random garbage when you read `$2` ...